# Simulate TXNs in most recent block

Tags: go-ethereum, hardhat, simulation

I want to be able to simulate transactions on top of the most recent block in a performant way (think a few milliseconds at most). I am trying to avoid having to host a local geth node, as it is expensive. One idea was using hardhat `npx hardhat node --fork $PROVIDER`, however this is usually a few blocks behind. I tried replaying all transactions in the missed blocks, and whenever a new block comes in, but it seems like this gets it out of sync with the real blockchain at some point.

Is there a better solution for this?